# Incompatibility of 'subcaption' package with [hebrew]{babel}

Tags: babel, subcaption, hebrew

I've come across a few posts now that try to deal with the issues bable has with Arabic and Hebrew and I know that the polyglossia package is recommended, however I am reluctant to rejig my entire document as I only need to insert 3 Hebrew letters in a separate line.

The error message I'm currently getting concerns an incompatibility with the {subcaption} package which I assume is due to the forced right-alignment of Hebrew?

I'd appreciate any suggestions including crude hacks. I've even looked into using the math mode which has some Hebrew letters, but sadly not the correct ones...

This is roughly what I've got:

```
\documentclass{Classes/PhDThesisPSnPDF}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %can't use utf8x either at it throws up even more error messages
\usepackage [english,hebrew]{babel}
\begin{document}
\foreignlanguage{hebrew}{בָּבֶל}
\end{document}
```

Comment: For just 3 letter very likely all you need is a font with these characters. Please, edit your question and add a minimal example.

Comment: Oh thanks, that pointed me in the right direction for googling - I seem to have found the solution with  the {cjhebrew} package!

Comment: Regarding the `hebrew` package and `caption` resp. `subcaption` you will find the actual status here: https://gitlab.com/axelsommerfeldt/caption/issues/29