# Subcaptions in Hebrew XeLaTeX

Tags: xetex, subcaption, hebrew

I have a pdfLaTeX document with lots of TikZ drawings placed in subfigures with individual captions (using the Springer class `svmono`). I tried to translate to Hebrew XeLaTeX using the `subcaption` package. It works except that the subcaptions are not numbered.

([Incompatibility of 'subcaption' package with [hebrew]{babel}](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/474705/175389) seems to deal with the issue but I want `subcaption` not `caption` and I'm using `polyglossia` not `babel`.)

Here is a MWE. I tried various commands from `subcaption` but nothing seems to work.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{polyglossia}  
\setmainlanguage{hebrew}
\newfontfamily{\hebrewfont}{David}[Script=Hebrew]

\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{hebrew}
מלבן גדול באיור%
~\ref{big-rectangle} 
ומלבן קטן באיור%
~\ref{small-rectangle}.

\begin{figure}
\subcaptionbox{מלבן גדול\label{big-rectangle}}
{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) rectangle +(5,3);
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\subcaptionbox{מלבן קטן\label{small-rectangle}}
{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) rectangle +(3,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

One more question: in the command `\subcaptionbox[list entry]...` what does `list entry` mean?

Comment: I'm not sure what the expected output should be. Do you want `[numerals=arabic]` to apply to the subcapions (as well as captions)? Or, like current output, `[numerals=hebrew]`?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, my bad, I didn't read the documentation thoroughly. My problem is not specific to Hebrew. I get the captions I want by adding the following to the preamble:

```
\DeclareCaptionSubType*{figure}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=simple}
\renewcommand\thesubfigure{איור~\thefigure(\alph{subfigure})}
```

and I remove the explicit איור from the reference:

```
מלבן גדול ב%
\ref{big-rectangle}.
\ref{small-rectangle}
מראה מלבן גדול.
```

The result is:[image]